# Why are there no commas after some prepositional phrases and not others?

Tags: commas

Why is that in sentence 1 below, a comma before "of" is permitted?

> 1. Detective Polly found that, of the hundreds of cases of malaria near the river, all but three involved near the contaminated pump.

For sentence 2, why do we have to have a comma between "program" and "from"?

> 2. They now operate from 12 to 2pm, and the government funds every aspect of the program, from the jerseys to the coaches.

Is the 2 the same as 3? Why is the comma between "processes" and "cellular division" legal? I feel that sentence 2 and 3 are the same as sentence 4.

> 3. The energy contained in these molecules can then be used to activate a number of biological processes, from cellular division to muscle contraction

For sentence 4, why is that we can't have a comma between "VP" and "about"?

> 4. I signaled to the VP about the wrinkle on his tie.

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: Yes and where's your own analysis, please?

Comment: No, I'm trying to understand why some sentences allow commas before the prepositional phrases as I was taught to not use a comma before or after a preposition.

Comment: @WillCrawford does this have to do with restrictive vs. non-restrictive clauses instead?

Comment: Honestly all I can tell you right now with my sleepy brain is that's the way that looks right. The last one, I think would be quite readable even with a comma there, it just isn't necessary. You possibly need to stop thinking of those commas as coming "after" anything, but rather "between".

Comment: Or in one case, "around".

Comment: I'll go out on limb and suggest that 2 and 3 are pretty much identical, and that the main reason the comma is legal is that in both cases you can remove the part after the comma without significantly affecting the meaning, i.e. the first part is a completely independent clause; and "from X to Y" is as you suggest a “non-restrictive clause”. The first one is more complex but you really need to tackle it a bit on your own first.

Comment: Thank you Will. I'm reading it several times and I think it has to do with essential (restrictive clauses). That should determine whether a comma is needed. @RobbieGoodwin what do you think?

Comment: I wasn’t ignoring you… just had a major crash to cope with. Don’t you think this belongs on English Language Learners? I seem to remember it should have been dealt with in British schools by around age 12, if not in primary school. 

Your examples 1-3 don’t have to have commas; they’re optional, assuming the gap missed out near Polly’s pump changes nothing.

Consider how any of them might be re-written and compare that to your 4, where neither part of the phrase could make sense without the other.